# How to create a Gmail addon?

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons

How can I create a Gmail addon? I don't find any API to do it.

Comment: Gmail doesn't have an addon system (as far as I know); could you show us an example of what you mean?

Comment: sure! rapportive for example. something like that.

Comment: Aha. That's not an addon for Gmail, it's an addon for browsers that modifies the way Gmail works. It doesn't use an API for that, since it's not integrated in Gmail, it's integrated in the browser. When Gmail loads, the addon notices it's his turn and kicks in. Rapportive probably uses the Google Contacts API (http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/) to access contact information.

Comment: haaa.. :) thank you! I thought it was something like that since they have: "addon for firefox, safari, chrome" but I wasn't sure. Ok, thank you!

Comment: Gmail finally supports Add-Ons (for people reading these comments) , Look at my answer below.

Comment: Easiest way (ie without having to publish stuff through official channels) is to use https://script.google.com/home to create an apps script project, and then share that project. Example: https://programmable101.wordpress.com/2018/05/30/google-mail-apps-script-dont-send-mails-from-your-contacts-to-the-gmail-spam-folder/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can however add scripted gadgets to the sidebar, or triggered by email content:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

Answer (score 18):

Gmail finally supports ADD-ONS now in Oct, 2017.

You can read the documentation here -
https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/

This Add-Ons will work on Gmail web-app and Android App. iOS support should come soon.

But still you can't publish your Add-Ons yet as mentioned here - https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish

Support to publish should come soon, however you can still develop and test for that early mover advantage.

However you can use few which are already published - 
https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail

Answer (score 5):

Google has recently introduced add-ons for Gmail (probably on Oct, 24 2017). It can be developed with Google Apps Script. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) says

**What Gmail add-ons can do ?**

> Displaying additional information for the user in the Gmail UI.
>   Connecting to non-Google services, to retrieve information or take other actions.
>   Providing an interactive interface to allow the user to control the add-on or send information to another service.

As of now, Google [is not allowing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish) to publish new add-ons however they will allow it in future.

> While a few add-ons have been made available in the G Suite
>   Marketplace for users to install, it is not currently possible to
>   publish your own add-on to the Marketplace.

**How can you publish your own add-on ?**

As of now (26th Oct, 2017), they consider it on request basis. If you have a cool idea, [fill this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform) to let them know about it. You will get notified once they accept your listing.

**Here is how the add-on interface looks like inside Gmail**

[image]