# Email developments- such as plugins

Tags: python, email, gmail

I just learnt Python and PHP, I want to develop a plugin for gmail, which fetches all the contacts from my gmail account. I have no idea where to start. Can anyone suggest where to look for, how to develop and which engine(eclipse, netbeans etc )  to use. I would be very happy to receive as much information as possible, so that i can conclude my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436068/how-to-create-a-gmail-addon

Answer (score 0):

first i would take a look at google's gmail api for python

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python

there also seems to be support for getting contacts in gmail

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts

I highly recommend learning about HTTP protocols and internet structure in general. The more you know the more it will make sense. Also if you are dealing with downloading and uploading emails I would also recommend researching programs using SMTP, POP3, or IMAP.

Oh and as far as what IDE to use it really comes down to personal preference. I do a lot of my development just using vim which is a text editor and command line tools. But many like the benefits IDEs provide. Generally I find vim to be enough.